# BeautifulSoup: Parse children by tag name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, parent-child

I have a xml with coordinates like this:

```
<geo>
 <lat>52.5025100</lat>
 <lng>13.3086000</lng>
</geo>
```

I can parse the string of the first and second child (that get stored in a list) like this:

```
child_1=soup.find('geo').contents[1].get_text(strip=True)
child_2=soup.find('geo').contents[3].get_text(strip=True)
```

Suppose I have to process several files and I'm not sure whether lat and long always appear in the above order, indexing would not work because it is not reliable. Rather than this I would like to parse lat and long with their tag-names as children of `geo`.

This does not work:

```
child_1=soup.find('geo').contents('lat').get_text(strip=True)
```

So how could i achieve this?

**Note**: `lat` and `long` appear several times in the doc. Therefore I can't parse the doc directly for `lat` and `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly access the child elements of a node using its [tag name](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names):

```
geo = soup.find('geo')
print geo.lat.get_text(strip=True)
print geo.lng.get_text(strip=True)
```